# Java: Read from Multiple Lines (External File)

Tags: java

I am trying to display the contents of multiple rows in a text file. I can do it no problem with a single line, but I add another line and I'm not sure what I need to add to my code to make it move on to the next line. I need myValues[1] to be the same as myValues[n] only to be the second line in the file. I believe I need to se a new String as the next line but I'm not sure exactly how with this setup.

```
package a3;
import java.io.*;
public class A3
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String animals = "animals.txt";
        String line = null;

        try
        {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(animals);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            String aLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            String myValues[] = aLine.split(" ");

            int n = 0;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(myValues[n] + " " + myValues[1]);
                n++;
            }   
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + animals + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error reading file '" + animals + "'");                  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should separate the handling of first line split (array `myValues`) and reading the next lines. In your while loop you are reading all lines of the file beginning with the second. But you do nothing with it. Instead you are accessing `myValues`? This is very confusing.

Comment: What I was hoping for was aLine to be the 1st line, then make a bLine for the second. And be able to split each. I can't seem to make that work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple way to read lines from a file and do the processing:
There is a `java.io.LineNumberReader` class which helps do it.

Sample snippet:

```
LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));
String line = null;
while ((line = lnr.readLine()) != null)
{
    // Do you processing on line
}
```

Comment: I researched the LineNumberReader and had some success. I can't manipulate the data as fluidly as I'd like but this did set me on the path I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the array `myValues` is never changed and always contains the values for the first line of text. You need to change it each time you get a new line, this is done in your `while` loop :

```
[...]
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            myValues[] = line.split(" ");
            System.out.println(myValues[n] + " " + myValues[1]);
            n++;
        }
```

Obviously not tested...

Answer (score 0):

You could also read all lines to a String list like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;


List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(new File(animals).toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

And than iterate over the line list, split the values and output them.